# What is a GUI element with a filling-up rectangle shape called?

Tags: gui, terminology, ui-design

After every game of StarCraft 1, the statistics screen shows up. The part I like on this screen is the points counter. It starts from zero and then it counts up to the points you have achieved, with a filling-up rectangle shape based on the number it represents.

What is this type of counter called?

[image: StarCraft score screen]

For example, the *Units* bar for *Alpha Squadron* counts from 0 to 4975.

Comment: I don't think there is a special name for this one other than "Score" or "Global Score". However, some RTS displayed some graphs for the evolution of the research score, combat score and so on. It's up to you to define them in your games. To create them, you have to track every event with its time, its point and its type (Research/Combat/...) for every player.

Comment: I don't think it has a specific name except maybe: "animated score" or "animated score counter"?

Comment: Progress bar? :)

Comment: No but I can make screenshot. :) @Kikamaru well part of it looks like progress bar :)

Comment: Progress bars are usually the simplest way to achieve that effect. You just set the max value to the highest points some player has achieved in the category and the value to whatever current player has achieved. As far as the name goes I think most of us just call them progress bars / point meters.

Comment: @Vlad, In SC2 the counter-score is much, much nicer. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The item you're talking about would be referred to as a progress bar:

[image]

In this case, the progress bar is animated to fill up over a small amount of time. When completely full, the progress bar matches the highest score for that category.

So, where `4975` is equal to 100% of the bar being full, `2000` is `2000/4975 = .40` or 40% full, as you can see in your example image:

[image]

You can animate these in the standard fashion of adding to their value by a small amount each frame until they are set to their desired value.

```
Update() {
    if(currentValue < targetValue)
        currentValue += increment;
}
```

Or in a more controlled manner with a time step included in the calculation.

Comment: Note that some GUI systems distinguish progress bars from *meters*. In that case, progress bars may be animated to suggest a task in progress, and meters not. You would use a meter for e.g. an amount of a resource that could go up or down and isn't necessarily expected to hit the limit.